# How can I identify this "search syntax" or "query language"?

Tags: database, search, syntax, relational-database, reverse-engineering

Can anyone identify this 'search syntax' or 'query language' ?
I am looking for a more complete specification.

- There is one operator:  `=`
- All strings are case-insensitive, limited to 7-bit
- Whitespace is significant
- Queries are of the form:   `column=value`
- `&` is a query seperator, leading to `column1=value1&column2=value2` for an INTERSECTION
- Data typing is implicit, and has at least strings, booleans, and positive decimal values
- Positive decimal numbers have syntax similar to the following:

  - `value=-10.0` returns all results with value less-than-or-equal to 10
  - `value=10+` returns all results with value greater-than-or-equal to 10
  - `value=1:10.0` returns all results between 1 and 10, inclusively
- Booleans:

  - False can be represented as : `bool=0`,`bool=f`,`bool=false`
  - True can be represented as:  `bool=0`, `bool=t`,`bool=true`
- Strings:

  - Do not need to be wrapped in quotes, quotes are ignored
  - `?` is a single-character wildcard,  `*` is a multi-character (can be empty) wildcard

What I've looked at so far:

1. `Lucene`, which uses `:` for seperator, and is more complex syntatically
2. `SQL where-clauses` which use far more extensive operators
3. `HQL` and `.QL` (and others from Wikipedia's query pages) - however, this is significantly less object based.

Given the complexity, including implicit type conversions, I don't believe this was a home-grown DSL.

Comment: I don't know about the syntax but probably one reason why you have not gotten an answer yet is, that you only tagged the question with [database] and [dql] even when you are indicating that the question might nothing have to do with databases and from my side i can say that this question has NOTHING todo with the doctrine query language which isn't hard to figure out when visiting the corresponding doctrine documentation for a minute. Maybe check if there is a tag for unknown syntaxes, i would bet there one or have you already done that?

Comment: Context & example please.